# Desabilitar botão após o click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom estou tendo o seguinte problema. O jQuery identifica a tag `data-link` para recuperar o link e redirecionar a página. Logo após isso o botando tem que ser desabilitado.

O problema e que ao clicar no botão ele e desabilitado e não é redirecionado.

Como faço para ele ser desabilitado só depois? Isso e para evitar um duplo clique.

```js
$("body").on('click', '[data-link]', function() {

  console.log($(this).data('link'));

  // Verifica se tem link
  if (typeof $(this).data('link') !== 'undefined') {
    document.location.href = $(this).data('link');
  }
});


$(document).ready(function () {
   
    // verificação de clieque
    $("button").click(function () {
        
        if(!$(this).disabled){

            // Desabilita o botao
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type='submit' data-link="http://www.google.com">OK</button>

<br>
<Br><br><br>

<div data-link="http://www.google.com">OK</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Você definiu dois comportamentos para o evento click do botão

- `$('body').on('click', '[data-link]', function() { ... });`
- `$('button').click(function () { ... });`

O javascript irá adotar um ou outro, no seu caso, quando chama o click do botão está invocando o último declarado `$('button').click(function () { ... });`, em nenhum momento irá chamar a primeira opção.

### Como resolver esse problema?

Declare toda sua função em apenas um evento, poderá ficar assim:

```
$("body").on('click', '[data-link]', function() {
  var enderecoLink = $(this).data('link');
  if (enderecoLink)
    document.location.href = enderecoLink;

  $(this).prop('disabled', !$(this).disabled);
});
```

### Como saber qual função está sendo chamada?

Você pode utilizar as opções de [debug](http://blog.da2k.com.br/2015/01/10/debugar-javascript-no-browser/) do navegador e adicionar `break points`.

## Função do location.href

O [location.href](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) irá redirecionar o usuário (na mesma aba) para o endereço que você definir, ou seja, o botão que foi clicado não existirá mais, pois estará em um novo endereço/site/url...

Para continuar na sua página e abrir uma nova, utilize [window.open](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) ao invés do `location.href`

```
$("body").on('click', '[data-link]', function() {
  var enderecoLink = $(this).data('link');
  if (enderecoLink)
    window.open(enderecoLink);

  $(this).prop('disabled', !$(this).disabled);
});
```

A documentação é o melhor lugar para você obter informações e aprender a utilizar os recursos que você está usando, então leia sem medo. :)

Answer (score 4):

Hugo, assim não te serviria?

```js
$("body").on('click', '[data-link]', function() {

  console.log($(this).data('link'));
  // Verifica se tem link
  if (typeof $(this).data('link') !== 'undefined') {
    document.location.href = $(this).data('link');
  }

  if (!$(this).disabled) {
    // Desabilita o botao
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type='submit' data-link="http://www.google.com">OK</button>

<br>
<Br><br><br>

<div data-link="http://www.google.com">OK</div>
```